# Magento: Admin Form Contains Abstract Method -> Error

Tags: php, class, magento, abstract-class, implements

I'm getting following error when I acces my form:

```
Class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Option_Edit_Tab_Form contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface::getTabLabel) in C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\app\code\local\MP\Search\Block\Adminhtml\Option\Edit\Tab\Form.php on line 169
```

I already implemented *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface*:

```
class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Option_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {

   public function getTabTitle() {
      return Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Conditions');
   }

   public function canShowTab() {
      return true;
   }

   public function isHidden() {
      return false;
   }
}
```

So what am I missing?

Edit: I added the methods that are probably causing the error.
From what I understand I need to implement `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface` for those to work.
As you can probably tell now, my goal is to implement a Condition Field in my "Option" Form.

Answer (score 0):

If you  are trying to extend form class then try like this :

```
class MP_Search_Block_Adminhtml_Option_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
```

Comment: Sry I'm not sure what you mean. I do extend from Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form, as you can see in the question. Do you mean to try it without
"implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface"? This wont work since I need that class for some methods. I'll add them in the question. Thanks for the answer.